# Properties of functions on topological spaces

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Three questions follow which are related to concept of topological spaces and functions defined thereon.

> a)Let $F$ be a family of functions on a compact topological space $X$ such that it is closed under multiplication of functions and for every $x\in X\exists$ an open neighbourhood $U$ such that the restriction of a function $f\in F$ is identically zero. Then, does the zero function belong to $F$?
>
> b)Is the space of Lipschitz continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with lipschitz constant $k=1$ compact under the sup-norm?
>
> c)If a family of functions belonging to the set of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ has the property that every subfamily vanish a certain point, then does there exist a point which is a common zero for all members of the family?

Am totally clueless on the three problems, though I think all are true. May be, for a), the existence of a finite subcover for every open cover has a role to play. As for b), I have a feeling that it is false since the limit of a sequence of lipschitz functions need not be lipschitz. Again, for c), since the family of functions need not be equicontinuous, therefore the conclusion may be false.
Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Don't you want to assume that $F$ consists of continuous functions in part a)?

Comment: @uniquesolution no, the family is arbitrary.

Comment: b) is an application of Arzela-Ascoli. c) smells false to me too.

Answer (score 1):

First a correct statement of a is needed.  When you say: 
for every $x\in X, \exists$ an open neighbourhood $U$ such
that the restriction of a function $f\in F$ vanishes over,
do you mean for each $f\in F$ or for some f?
If the former, then F contains only the zero function.

Otherwise, for each $x \in X$, there is a $f_x \in F$ and some
open $U_x$ over which $f_x$ is 0.  The $U_x$'s cover X.
So there is a finite subcover { $U_{x1},.. U_{xk}$ } covering X.
Show that $f_{x1} ×..× f_{xk}$ is the desired zero function.

This is a standard proof method for compact spaces.

Comment: thanks, i meant for some $f\in F$. what about b),c)?

Comment: @vidyarthi.  c is trivial because the whole collection is a subfamily.  I leave b for your intertainment.